# Iphone position:fixed; alternative?

Tags: css

Well i'm using `position:fixed;` for a sidebar and footer, so when you scroll they will stay in place while the main content moves(`position:static;`). But when you zoom in or more `Left/Right` it is not showed on the screen anymore.

Here is a good explanation of the problem i'm having [here](http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/IPad-safari-browser-tp4713039p6004296.html)

*"Safari on iPad and Safari on iPhone do not have resizable windows. In Safari on iPhone and iPad, the window size is set to the size of the screen (minus Safari user interface controls), and cannot be changed by the user. To move around a webpage, the user changes the zoom level and position of the viewport as they double tap or pinch to zoom in or out, or by touching and dragging to pan the page. As a user changes the zoom level and position of the viewport they are doing so within a viewable content area of fixed size (that is, the window). This means that webpage elements that have their position "`fixed`" to the viewport can end up outside the viewable content area, offscreen."*

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery UI could solve [this](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/).

> The most notable improvements in 1.1.0 are true fixed toolbars

Answer (score 0):

It's often ill advised to use fixed content on mobile because of this reason, but also because the screen real estate is small and valuable. You could get around it by disabling zooming in the meta viewpoint, but I'd discourage that as well as it affects the users experience given that they are used to being able to zoom. It's not an answer, but a few suggestions. Something to consider.